# Is hiding the post button a valid way to prevent a user from posting without permission?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have some comment forms that I want to not be used unless the user is logged in with Google+.  I initially have the "submit" button on my forms hidden by the CSS display:none property.  I call javascript when the user logs in to change it back to display:inline.

Is this a valid way to prevent anonymous users from posting, or am I still vulnerable by leaving the rest of the comment form open for writing and whatnot...is there some clever way to submit the form without the submit button?

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form1" id="make">
<fieldset>
<legend id="makelegend">Log in to Post a Reference</legend>
<input type="hidden" name="loginname" id="loginname" />
<input type="hidden" name="logintype" id="logintype" />
<input type="hidden" name="loginspecial" id="loginspecial" />
<input type="hidden" name="reply" id="reply" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="identity" id="identity" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['pageno']); ?>" />
    <p><label for="posneg">Positive or Negative?
    <select name="posneg">
    <option value="p">Positive</option>
    <option value="n">Negative</option>
    </select></label></p>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="70"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submitter" value="POST" style="display:none;" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to check that at the back-end. There is no need to use your form to post to your server, anybody can do that directly so the only way to insure the user is authorized, is by doing that at the top of your script on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ABSOLUTELY NOT safe! You're just not displaying the data to the user, but anyone who looks at the code can still find it - or just send the request manually. I can't stress this enough: ALWAYS use server-side validation! It's fine to validate things in the browser as well, but it's not a substitute for proper security measures.

Comment: Hmm...that presents a problem because I don't know what I can see any way of logically verifying that a post came from a person logged in with Google+.

Comment: Well, if you use Google's API, you can verify through that. But if you don't, I'm afraid there's probably no solution. Sorry. :/